how to edit saved images on a collection view
In my swift code in class twoViewcontroller it displays a uicollectionview and saved images where you can view the image or delete the image. What I would like to do is be able to edit the image in the same way I can create the image. Ideally what I want to do is click on the show button and be able to move around the rectangles for the original image.

class twoViewController: UIViewController {
    var itemName : [Item] = []
    
    fileprivate let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cv.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        return cv
    }()
    
    var backButton = UIButton()
    @objc func moveLeft() {
        
        
        
        
        
        let vcx = ViewController()
        vcx.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vcx, animated: true)}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        do {
            self.itemName = try managedContext.fetch(fetch)
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not load. \(error)")
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //        setupCollection()
        loadData()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPurple
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        backButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        backButton.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        //
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
        
        
        view.addSubview(backButton)
        
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveLeft), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9, constant: 0),
            collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier:  1, constant: 0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            
            
            backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0),
            backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier:  1, constant: 0),
            backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            
            
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue, .systemYellow, .systemPurple]

}
extension twoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    }

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
          let padding: CGFloat = 10
          let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width - padding
          let itemWidth = collectionViewWidth / 2 // Adjust the divisor for larger or smaller cells
          let itemHeight = itemWidth * 1.2 // Height can be proportional to width for a balanced look

          return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
      }
      
    
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemName.count
    }
    
 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
        let attr1 = title.value(forKey: "atBATS") as? String
        
        let text = ["  ", attr1].compactMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)

        if let imageData = itemName[indexPath.row].image {
            let coredataLoadedimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.ii.image = coredataLoadedimage
        }
        
        cell.parentVC = self
        cell.tt.text = text
        
        // Cycle through colors based on index
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]
        
        cell.bt2.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.bt2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(elete), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return cell
    }

    
    
    @objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
        
        
        let note = itemName[sender.tag]
        
        
        let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        managedContext.delete(note)
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        
        
    }
}





class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var parentVC: UIViewController!
    
    var  bg: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return iv
    }()
    
    var  bt: UIButton = {
        let bt = UIButton()
        bt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bt.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        bt.clipsToBounds = true
        bt.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return bt
    }()
    
    var  bt2: UIButton = {
        let bt2 = UIButton()
        bt2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bt2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        bt2.clipsToBounds = true
        bt2.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        return bt2
    }()
    
    var  tt: UILabel = {
        let tt = UILabel()
        tt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tt.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        tt.clipsToBounds = true
        return tt
    }()
    
    var  ii: UIImageView = {
        let ii = UIImageView()
        ii.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ii.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        ii.clipsToBounds = true
        return ii
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        [bt2, bt, ii, tt].forEach({
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.contentView.addSubview($0)
        })
        
        bt.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPink
        bt2.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        bt.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
        bt2.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
        
        ii.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
        tt.textAlignment = .center
        
        // Set up the layout constraints for image, label, and buttons
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ii.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            ii.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            ii.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            ii.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            
            tt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ii.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            tt.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            tt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
            tt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            bt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tt.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            bt.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            bt.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            bt.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            bt2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tt.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            bt2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            bt2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            bt2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
        
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func moveRight() {
        let vce = fullScreen()
        vce.text = tt.text!
        vce.newImage = ii.image!
        vce.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // .fullScreen can be used
        parentVC.present(vce, animated: true)
    }
}


... and where is the problem?

@MartinM if you see the image all you can do is select show and it will show the image. You cant move the rectangle via pan gesture like you could when you create the image. I want to be able to select the show button and then be brought to an editor where you can rearrange the rectangles.

@SamBurns - you probably want both "Save" and "Export" options. "Save" would store the rectangles data somewhere - frames, colors, etc. When you display the image, re-create the rectangles and allow them to be moved/sized. The "Export" option would then generate a bitmap (png or jpg, etc) of the rendered image.
